# can i use arithmetic expressions in sql prepared statements?

Tags: sql

I had a query like following

```
UPDATE NOTIFICATION_MASTER 
   SET PARTICIPANT_COUNT = ? * LIKE_COUNT 
                              + ? * POST_COUNT 
                              + ? * VIEWS 
 WHERE ID = ? 
       AND CORP_ID = ?;
```

will it work?

Comment: If you replace the `?` with proper values and the fields you use is from `NOTIFICATION_MASTER` and the data types of the fields is `int` or something like that then, yes it will work.

Comment: In other words, if you replace all the `?`s with some relevant constants and run it and it does not produce errors, then it will work with `?`s just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes, but your DBMS may ask you to specify types with `cast` like `... + cast(? as int) + cast(? as int) ...`